# Solo block verification

Tags: blocks

If I have one block from bitcoin blockchain. I can check that block is valid without having the previous blocks. (solo block verification)

Imagine I have one block from Ethereum blokchain. Can I check that block is valid without  having the previous block?

Comment: Hi there. Are you _sure_ it's possible to check the validity of a single Bitcoin block without reference to previous blocks? Do you have a link to some details of how this works?

Comment: To verify a bitcoin block, we need to just make sure the transactions merkle root is correct. In Ethereum above of that we have storage tree and state tree.

Answer (score 0):

Having the block by itself only allows you to verify the transactions it contains and that the proof of work is correct, it does not let you on its own verify if it's part of the longest and therefore correct chain. For that you'd require the previous blocks. Same goes for Bitcoin.

Comment: Same for Bitcoin? There is no storage or state tree in bitcoin. Only transactions.

Comment: A single bitcoin block still only allows you to verify the contained transactions, not whether it's part of the longest chain.

Comment: having two or three blocks is fair enough to make sure a transaction is correct. In bitcoin of course.